# Json.Net serialization of classes that contain override methods

Tags: json.net

I am getting an exception when I attempt to serialize the following classes using  Json.Net:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Name = "child", Namespace = "")]
public class Child
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract(Name = "parent", Namespace = "")]
public class Parent
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "children", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) 
    {
        Parent parent = (Parent)obj;
        return parent.Id.Equals(Id);
    }
}
```

Here is the serialization code:

```
SortedDictionary<int, Parent> parents = new SortedDictionary<int, Parent>
{
    { 
        1, 
        new Parent 
        { 
            Id = 1, 
            Children = new List<Child> 
            { 
                new Child 
                { 
                        Id = 2 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parents);
```

Here is the exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Child]' to type 'Parent'.
```

If I remove the `Equals` override method, the serialization occurs without error.  If, instead I remove the `List<Child>` property from the `Parent` class the serialization also works without error.

Can someone please help to me understand why the override method appears to break serialization in this way?  Is there a way around it?

Comment: Noticed this problem too, haven't found a solution yet.  Have you?

Comment: I have not, but then again I put the project that was using it on hold so I have not been actively working on it.  I think to get around it quickly I commented out the override method.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet you $1 that this issue has nothing to do with the use of override methods in the class being serialized.  It's the unchecked cast in `Equals()`.  The serialization code may call `.Equals()` to check for cycles or for any other reason - I'll bet this fixes the problem:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) 
{
    Parent parent = obj as Parent;
    return (parent != null) && parent.Id.Equals(Id);
}
```

Comment: Had an issue and couldn't figure out why it was reaching stack overflow error. Adding type check solved my issue.